animate tailwind tabs component
I created a simple tabs component using tailwind and svelte, like the following one:

you can see it working on this repl
I'd like to animate the transition from one option to the other
Similar to what happens in this page: https://www.shadcn-svelte.com/examples/dashboard

How could I achieve such animation, either using tailwind classes or svelte directives?

One approach is to draw an element under the tabs and move that around, the movement then can be animated using a transition.
E.g.
let buttons = [];
$: ({ left, top, width, height } = (() => {
    const button = buttons[options.findIndex(o => o == value)];
    if (button == null)
        return { }; // Not mounted yet

    return button.getBoundingClientRect();
})())

<div class="... isolate"> <!-- Prevent z-index leakage -->
    <div
        class="absolute bg-white rounded-md transition-all"
        style="
            left: {left}px;
            top: {top}px;
            width: {width}px;
            height: {height}px;
        "></div>
    {#each options as option, i}
        <button
            bind:this={buttons[i]}
            on:click={() => (value = option)}
            class="z-10 ..."
            >{option}</button
        >
    {/each}
</div>

REPL
The shadcn-svelte site uses a Svelte crossfade transition:
import { cubicInOut } from "svelte/easing";
import { crossfade } from "svelte/transition";

const [send, receive] = crossfade({
    duration: 250,
    easing: cubicInOut,
});

{#if isActive}
    <div
        class="bg-muted absolute inset-0 rounded-full"
        in:send={{ key: "activetab" }}
        out:receive={{ key: "activetab" }}
    />
{/if}

Crossfades have issues with transparency (overlaying two partially transparent elements does not yield a fully opaque area), but even then it probably would not be very visible for small elements like this.
REPL

excellent answer and explanation! I also had a look at the way shadcn-svelte solves it and came to something pretty similar to your second example. the first one is pretty clever too btw. Thanks a lot, this should be part of shadcn-svelte library
